How to store textarea value as it is in Laravel Controller?
I have a textarea value which i need to save into database as it ..
Suppose the textarea value is like this:

I’m State Representative Naydu. I am sending you this message to let
you know that I have filed for re-election today. I hope I can count
on your support for our campaign!
https://secure.actblue.com/donate/reelectnaydu?refcode=filingtxt
Reply STOP to opt out

So I want to save it in database like this,

I’m State Representative John Bryant. I am sending you this message to
let you know that I have filed for re-election today. I hope I can
count on your support for our campaign!
\n\nhttps://secure.actblue.com/donate/reelectnaydu?refcode=filingtxt\n\nReply
STOP to opt out

I have saved it with this $communication->communication_text = $request->message; line. But can't save it as expected. How can I do it?
I want to send the variable to a Curl request to send API request like this
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                        "bulkId": "'.$communication->id.'",
                        "messages": [
                        {
                        
                        "destinations": [
                        ' . implode(',', $destinations) . '
                        ],
                        "from": "'. $sender->sender_number.'",     
                        "text": ".$communication->communication_text."
                        }
                        ],
                        "tracking": {
                        "track": "SMS",
                        "type": "MY_CAMPAIGN"
                        }
                        }',

But I got parsing Error:

"{"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"BAD_REQUEST","text":"Error
while parsing request body. Please check your syntax."}}}"

Here is the snap of $communication->communication_text, If i hard coded the text everythings works fine, when i pass it from controller i got parsing Error.


How is it saving it instead?

it saved as it like space and all but when i pass the variable in controller  and send to  API  i got error like "{"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"BAD_REQUEST","text":"Error while parsing request body. Please check your syntax."}}}"

Sounds like the problem is with what kind of request your API expects.  Laravel saves the data fine, that I've noticed.  If you echo out the db entry back into the textarea you should get what you put there.

How are you sending the API request in the first place?  That's where I'd check first.

Your problem is that you're constructing JSON by hand.  This will usually always lead to errors, whether it be by unescaped special characters or quote marks.
You're in luck though, because there is a solution: json_encode.
Simply, you can do this for your API request:
$destinationsMapped = [];
foreach ($destinations as $destination) {
  $destinationsMapped[] = ['to' => (string) $destination];
}

$data = [
    'bulkId' => $communication->id,
    'messages' => [
        [
            'destinations' => $destinationsMapped,
            'from' => $sender->sender_number,
            'text' => $communication->communication_text
        ]
    ],
    'tracking' => [
        'track' => 'SMS',
        'type' => 'MY_CAMPAIGN'
    ]
];

// ...
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data)
//...

Note that the array format is based on the data you gave in your question, but you might still need to adjust it. json_encode takes care of the JSON-ification for you.

Actually I tried with your solution before i even posted here. But same error I'm getting.

@Hola What API are you using?

Infobip : https://www.infobip.com/docs/api/channels/sms/sms-messaging/outbound-sms/send-sms-message

@Hola Your destinations field does not follow what is recommended by that API page.  I'll update my answer to reflect what it appears to expect.

I have updated the question. please check once.

There is no problem with destinations that i have already updated like this:
$destinations = [];
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) 
    {
        $destinations[] = '{
            "to": "' . $contact->contact_number . '"
        }';
    }


@Hola Can you humor me and not code it that way?  That's encoded  json in json that is about to be encoded.  In other words, it does the encoding twice for that piece of data, thereby making it not match the expected schema of the API.  There does not appear to be anything wrong with the data that you dd()ed.

Cool brother, i was not expecting that causes the error..Thanks!

You can use the base64 encoding to store the data in a database. If you want to retrieve the data convert it into base64 decode(base64_decode).
$communication->communication_text = base64_encode($request->message);

is there any other way? because base64 consumes more memory , i want to save it lightly .

Why don't you try "zlip". It will compress the value and store it in a database. It's taking less memory.
-> gzcompress
-> gzdecode

Encoding to base64 makes no sense at all. The question is about saving a string to a DB, which can easily be done without encoding it to base64.
